# The relationship between the two red filled square boxes with the dotted line represents what kind of relationship?

Tags: entity-relationship

[image]
I understand this drawing as an "n - 1" relationship, meaning many tabs belonging to one field.

I would like to know, based on the provided image, what the relationship between those two tables is.

Comment: It is the opposite, multiple fields can belong to one tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have seen and updated it